# Python listen for mouse button click

Tags: python, python-3.x, winapi, pywin32

I want to listen for mouse button click. How can I do that with pywin32?
My solution is bad cause CPU 45%...
As I understand, I need something like GetMessage, but I dont know how to do it correctly.

My current solution:

```
while True:
        if win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(win32con.VK_XBUTTON1) != 0 :
            ...
```

Comment: A click in your application, or any time the mouse is clicked?

Comment: any time in any window

Comment: Does this solution work (meaning it detects any mouse click)? The only drawback is that it's using half of the *CPU*? How can you be sure of that? How many cores do you have? What is the other code looking like? [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: yes, it works. and yes, it detects mouse x1 button clicks. what's the point of making it so complicated? when this program runs with this loop, the CPU load increases dramatically. when I use the "mouse" library, there is no such thing. However, the library does not always work.